# Spring 3 MVC - View Resolver for JSP pages with no controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just started the spring 3 development and I had use spring 2.5 previously.
I got stuck with the View Resolver. I had the following configuration

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And yes it works if the jsp pages is in the /WEB-INF/jsp path. The problem that I stumble is that if I had a jsp inside (e.g. /WEB-INF/jsp/prod/Monitor/success.jsp), I cannot get it to resolve the page if I type http://localhost/Project/prod/Monitor/success.html in the browser.

Did i miss anything here. Just for more info, the jsp will show up if the jsp had a controller, but I need it to resolve jsp pages with no controller associate with it.

Comment: Just add a simple controller for it.

Comment: If it doesn't need to pass through a controller, why is it a JSP? Change it to be a static HTML file and use @xueshi's answer about static resources.

Answer (score 4):

Add this into context:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/prod/Monitor/success.html" view-name="/prod/Monitor/success" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can treat these pages as static resources .
see [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) for details.